# spotfire: multiple scatter plots in a visualization

Tags: scatter-plot, spotfire

I am trying to draw 2 data GPS tables into 1 visualization in Tibco Spotfire. By setting columns latitude/longitude to X/Y axis, the first data source is visualized successfully. The error appears once I drag the column Latitude (from the second data source) into Y axis.

> Please specify an aggregation method. Expressions including other data
>   tables than the main data table must be aggregated.

[image]

Any idea pls?

Comment: try `max()` or `first()` if the values are unique

Comment: Ending up to use 1 scatter plot for all the points, then use Marker for different categories